# Triggering click events on an element in Javascript (with working iOpus iMacros example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, imacros

I am fairly new to Javascript / Jquery and my experience is limited to triggering basic Javascript functions (via the developer console) in order interact with webpages (Internet Explorer mostly). I have found that some pages are relatively simple, while other pages are more complex when it comes to interaction

I'm having some difficulty with a particular page (I am unable to disclose this page unfortunately). I took a look at the source code and it looks like the page verifies mouse position so that when it hovers over the button, it can then be clicked.

Interestingly enough, I tried a Firefox addon called iOpus iMacros and it worked perfectly. Unfortunately, iMacros doesn't resemble Javascript and I'd prefer to learn the correct way to do this using Javascript / Jquery. I have tried a hundred different things and nothing has seemed to work. A few examples I have tried are below:

**Unsuccessful:**

```
document.getElementById('#example-button').click();

document.select.getElementById('#example-button').click();

var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13;
e.keyCode = 13;
$("#example-button").trigger(e);
```

**Successful iOpus iMacros code that *did* work:
(mouse click):**

```
FRAME F=2
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#example-button" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#example-button2" BUTTON=0
```

**(via Enter key):**

```
FRAME F=2
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#example-button" KEY=13
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#example-button2" BUTTON=0
```

Comment: It's just `$(element).trigger('keypress')`, and that's it, but it will only trigger event handlers bound by jQuery etc.

Comment: You can use JavaScript in 'iMacros'. Check out [this link](http://wiki.imacros.net/URL#Using_Javascript) for reference.